# Java annotation implementation

Tags: java, annotations

I am new to java. Java is more dependent on annotations like in spring, lambok, jersey etc,. I know annotations are processed during compile time but I have no idea about how it is done. If I want to implement a simple annotations @get like in jersey how can I do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: search for a tutorial on Google may be because the answer would be very big to be given here.

Comment: I find it as very nice example from Mkyong : [Java Custom Annotations Example](https://www.mkyong.com/java/java-custom-annotations-example/)

Answer (score 0):

By using reflect methods, you can access `Methods` or `Fields`, or even `Classes` that you have annotated, then the annotation will be available as a classic object instance:

```
Get getInstance = field.getAnnotation(Get.class);
//or
Get getInstance = method.getAnnotation(Get.class); 
// Get is your annotation interface
```